# I made a discord bot with visual studios using pycord but my commands wont work?

Tags: discord, bots, pycord

The bot is running fine on its own but im unable to get it to interact with things said in chat. The code im using is below:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

with open("./config.json") as config_file:
    data=json.load(config_file)
token = data["token"]


description = "This is a bot custom designed for The Odyssey Discord"

intents=discord.Intents.all()


bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"), description=description, intents=intents)


filtered_words = ["bitch"]
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in message.content:
            print(f"message deleted! {message.content}")
            await message.delete()







@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is ready ")




@bot.slash_command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.respond(f"Our bots current ping is {bot.latency} seconds.")






bot.run(token)
```

I do have gateway intents enabled for commands and i've waited the "hour" for it to supposedly start working and they still wont work. I've tried a few different things but they simply wont work. Hopefully I can get some help with this. I'll be setting up cogs eventually but I just want to get the commands to actually work first.

Comment: So what part of the code isn't working exactly?

Comment: @Bart Im still very new so im not entirely sure what the issue is, but for the chat filter it doesnt "remove" the bad words if they are said, and for the slash commands they dont work at all. When I do /ping its supposed to give the bots ping, and the filter is supposed to delete the bad words if they are said  in the chat but neither of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue, you need to also have:

```
@commands.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    pass
```

Essentially establishing that it's an actual command for the discord server.